# Linq JObject query

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I have some problems with jobject and jarray linq query. I get this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type     'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.
```

My code:

```
string fetchResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sidebar, Formatting.Indented);
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(fetchResult);

var jsonModel = from item in (JArray)rss["RegistrationCase"]
                        select new DataList
                        {
                            RegistrationTypeName = item["RegistrationTypeName"].Value<string>(), };
```

If i remove (Jarray) i get: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

Json, jobject: e.g: i want RegistrationTypeName, FirstName and the value of JournalNumber.

```
{
"Status": null,
"RegistrationCase": {
"RegistrationTypeName": " ",
"ExpireDate": null,
"PersonId": 7,
"Person": {
  "FirstName": " ",
  "GenderValue": 2,
  "Gender": 2,
},
"UserId": 7,
"User": {
  "UserName": "NO-DOM\\wme",
  "LastName": null,
  "Id": 7,
},
"Transactions": [],
"Comments": [],
"CustomData": [
  {
    "Key": "JournalNumber",
    "Value": "0654-84148-00000-25",
    "Id": 3,
  },
  {
    "Key": "IsConsentGiven",
    "Value": "False",
    "Id": 4,
  },
  {
],
"FileId": null,
"File": null,
"Id": 7,
 }
}
```

Comment: can u post ur full json string & what u want to get too?

Comment: @ashok added some more json and some of the data i want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can get these values directly like :

```
   var RegistrationTypeName = rss["RegistrationCase"]["RegistrationTypeName"];
   var FirstName = rss["RegistrationCase"]["Person"]["FirstName"];
   var JournalNumber = rss["RegistrationCase"]["CustomData"][0]["Value"];
```

Comment: Followup question:) CustomData is dynamic, how can i search for "Key" and display "Value".

Comment: `var value = rss["RegistrationCase"]["CustomData"][key]["Value"];`

Comment: tried that, gives me: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "JournalNumber". Array position index expected.